# A parser-blocking, cross site

Tags: angular, hosting

antes que nada os pongo en situación.
He desarrollado una pequeña aplicación web en angular que usa un código aleatorio como opción (ruta de router /lista/:id), esto me funciona de maravilla en local(desarrollo), y permite que se pueda acceder al contenido simplemente conociendo este código. El problema viene al ponerlo en producción y colgarlo en Internet, la aplicación sigue funcionando a excepción de acceder directamente con el código en la url.
Me muestra estos dos warnigs y la página de no existe:

> Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead.
>
> A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script

Quiero pensar que esta relacionado con el dns de mi hosting pero quiero asegurarme un poco ya que soy bastante nuevo en esto. Parece como si el dns de mi host enviara tambien una opción que esta haciendo conflicto con la mia.

Comment: Creo que debe ser por el archivo `.htaccess`. Te dejo la información para [configurar el servidor en la guía de angular](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration) Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema estaba en que hay que añadir un .htaccess al servidor para que redirija al index.htlm las peticiones (cosas de usar rutes de angular).
A parte no conseguí que me funcionase el .htaccess que viene en el manual de angular, pero encontré este que si me funciona:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

La solución la encontré en otro post de stackoverflow [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes).